# button changes color even if it's already assigned

Tags: javascript, loops, click, addeventlistener, minesweeper

I have this problem: whenever I click on the div, I want to add background color. Forever. But background changes even if I click more (like a loop). How to set background color forever?

```
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.game div');
const liveNumber = document.querySelector('.lives-num');
let lives = 1;


function letTheGameBegin(e, r) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (rand < 40) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else if (rand < 60) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        lives++;
    } else if (rand < 90) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        lives--;
    } else {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
    liveNumber.innerHTML = lives;
    if (lives === 0) {
        //document.querySelector('.game-over').style.display = 'flex';
    }
}

blocks.forEach(block => block.addEventListener('click', letTheGameBegin));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you only want to run the JS once per div.

Try this example and see if its what you need: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huy841t0/)

```
function letTheGameBegin(e, r) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if(!e.target.style.backgroundColor){
        if (rand < 40) {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (rand < 60) {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
            lives++;
        } else if (rand < 90) {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            lives--;
        } else {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
        liveNumber.innerHTML = lives;
        if (lives === 0) {
            //document.querySelector('.game-over').style.display = 'flex';
        }
    }
}
```